# type casts of params hash values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, return-value, parameters

i have some troubles with understanding of "params" function in RoR.

let's assume that i have user Model.
the next code apperars in users controller and it's function is to process POST 'destroy' request. "current_user" function returns currently signed in user (an instance of User class I suggest). by comparing "current_user == params[:id]" 'destroy' function checks if user is trying to delete yourself

```
def destroy

    if current_user == params[:id]
        flash[:error] = "you cannot delete yourself!"
    else
        User.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "user deleted"
    end

    redirect_to(users_path)
end
```

So the problem is that chunk code works well. and I don't really understand why. My background is 3-years experience of C++/C# programming in university, so I presumed that such kind of comparsion should cause some type casts. In that case I think it would be User obj ---> string obj (OR string --> User???!!!!). 
Although I have a lot of questions about how Rails manages to compare User class and string class, I could make myself comfortable with this.

But what if I want to optimize this task and explicitly compare just IDs: the one stored in params[:id] as a string(??) and the other in current_user["id"] hash.

first is of string type and second is of integer, am I wrong? because "current_user["id"] == params[:id].to_i" causes error, that implies that params[:id] returns instance of User class o_O

thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for the `current_user` method? I would not expect `current_user == params[:id]` ever to return true, so I'm surprised that this code is working for you.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on as I don't know what the value of `current_user` or `params` is. You might want to check them with something like `Rails.logger.debug("params: #{params.inspect}")`. There might be some magic going on (like saying an object is equal to itself or its ID), but I would not expect a `User` compared to an integer to return `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all: get yourself a decent ruby book and read about it's dynamic type system and method execution. that should answer most of your questions that you have when you come from a language like c.

like the opperator overloading in c it's possible in ruby to implement custom behavior for things like `==`. this is very easy in ruby, because `==` is just a method. that's how you could write comparisons for multiple types of classes, even though those are not symmetric anymore.

in your case, the code that you provided is just wrong. comparing `current_user` with `params['id']` will always yield false.

you should write something like that:

```
user = User.find params[:id]
if current_user == user
  redirect_to users_path, :error => "you cannot delete yourself!"
else
  user.destroy
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "user deleted"
end
```

Comment: thank you for piece of advice! I have tried that approach already - it works. but my interest was in little improvements. I wanted not to compare User objects, which as I think undergoes full attributes comparations, but compare native simple types

Comment: there is no such thing as a native simple type in ruby. it's all objects and you need to know what `==` is doing anyways. nevertheless, `current_user == user` is good code style in comparison to what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you man, I get it! NEVERTHELESS, I would like to correct myself: term "native" was exessive here, I meant SIMPLE types. My english is still poor.

Answer (score 0):

Your current_user variable should contain the id in integer or string format. Or maybe your user model has a to_s method defined for user instances. In this case when trying to convert the object to a string (for the comparison with a string), this method will be called which will be returning the id in string format.
You should print both the current_user variable as well as the params[:id] to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this

```
if current_user.id.to_s == params[:id]
```

params[:id] is a string, and you should comparing it with the current_user's id , not current_user